Is there a mission type that offers more rewards than the others?
There are multiple different kinds of missions.
For example, recovering intelligence from a downed SEAF plane, rescuing civilians, and eradicating enemies, just off the top of my head (those aren't all of them).
What mission gives the best rewards out of those?
